# Input handling using while in c

Tags: validation, while-loop, user-input

I want to make a program that handles the user input, more specifically the typed slashes ("/"). I used a variable to count them. The problem is, it says "error." every time I do a correct input, in this case 2 slashes (//).

THIS WORKS

Insert a string: //

ok.

THIS DOESN'T WORK

Insert a string: ///

error.

Insert a string: //

error.             - it should be "ok.". Why it says error?

I used to debug my program and found that the application never quits the while loop, so it doesn't know the final slash count value. I'm asking for help.

```
char input[50];
int slash_count = 0;
int i;
printf("Insert a string: ");
scanf("%s", input);
for(i=0; i<strlen(input); i++)
{
    if (input[i] == '/')
    {
        slash_count++;
    }
}
while (slash_count != 2)
{
    printf("error.\n");
    printf("Insert a string: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
}
printf("ok");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop should case over the entire

input -> check -> validate routine.

However, you have your while loop for re-trial

after the validation.

So if you have gotten 3 before,

and you get to re-try,

then your slash_count never gets updated.

```
int slash_count = 0;

while (slash_count != 2) {
    slash_count = 0;
    char input[50];
    printf("Insert a string: ")
    scanf("%s", input)
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if (input[i] == '/') {
            slash_count++;
            if (slash_count > 2) break;
        }
    }
}
printf("okay");
```

Comment: So basically I should put the for loop in a while loop.

Comment: you should put everything in the while loop.

Comment: the idea is, that your entire routine (get input -> validate) should be executed every time the input is invalid. However, since you're only re-executing the 'input' phase, slash_count will never be updated, and it will never be validated

Comment: No, you should put only the slash_count inside the while. It doesn't really matter but the code looks more readable this way. I've tried this and it works. Thanks. * Nevermind, it works without that variable too.